# Lower bounds for class number of function fields with fixed $q$, growing $g$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, finite-fields

Let $X$ be a smooth project curve of genus $g$ over the finite field with $q$ elements. Let $h$ be $\# \mathrm{Pic}^0(X)(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Weil showed that $h \geq (\sqrt{q}-1)^{2g}$. [Lachaud and Martin-Descamps](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/aa-56-4-329-340) established the bound $h \geq \tfrac{q^g}{g+1} \tfrac{(q-1)^2}{q(q+1)} \approx \tfrac{q^g}{g}$, which is better for $q$ fixed and $g \to \infty$.

I was playing around with the estimates I was using in a recent question about finding function fields with class number $1$, and I seem to have come up with an argument that proves a bound of the form $h \geq c \tfrac{q^g}{\log g}$, for a small positive constant $c$.

I am trying to figure out if this is interesting. Of course, I'm doing a literature search, but I don't know this area, so maybe someone can tell me. What are the best current bounds in this area, and how does mine compare? Or, I suppose, does someone know a counterexample showing that $\tfrac{q^g}{\log g}$ is too good to be true?

Comment: Maybe this recent paper is relevant?: https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02264

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks, but I don't think so. General abelian varieties are very different than Jacobians in this setting: There are infinitely many (simple, nonisogenous)  abelian varieties over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with $\#A(\mathbb{F}_2)=1$, but for Jacobians, $\#J(\mathbb{F}_2)$ goes to infinity as $g \to \infty$.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that you're looking at $q$ fixed and $g\to \infty$!

Comment: No problem. Also the bound in that paper is worse than the Lachaud and Martin-Descamps bound. (Which is not a criticism of that paper, because Lachaud and Martin-Descamps is only for Jacobians.)

Comment: In the special case of a hyperelliptic curve, I think this bound matches the standard analytic lower bound for $L(1,\chi)$ under GRH, applied to function fields. References to this bound outside the function field context surely exist, but I don't know what is available in the function field context, or if anyone has connected it to Jacobians.

Comment: A reference is Littlewood, On the class-number of the corpus $P(\sqrt{-k})$, Theorem 1, https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-27.1.358 $k$ would correspond to something like $q^{ 2g +2}$, so the $\log \log k$ appearing in Littlewood's formula is equal to $\log g$ up to a constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}$Easy results are usually not original, and this wasn't an exeption. What I was doing was almost exactly the same as [On the number of rational points of Jacobians over finite fields](https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/acta-arithmetica/all/169/4/83945/on-the-number-of-rational-points-of-jacobians-over-finite-fields), Lebacque and Zykin (2013). The one thing that they are missing is a simple asymptotic analysis, so I'll publish that here rather than trying to make it into a paper.

For any $N \geq 1$, Corollary 2.5 of Lebacque and Zykin implies that
$$\#J(\FF_q) \geq q^g \exp\left( - \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{q^{-n}}{n} - \frac{2g}{(\sqrt{q}-1)(N+1) q^{N/2}} \right).$$
$$= q^g \exp \left( - \log N + O(1) + O \left( \tfrac{g}{N q^{N/2}} \right) \right).$$
If we choose $N$ such that $q^{N/2} \approx 2g$, then we get a lower bound of $c \tfrac{q^g}{\log g} $.